# Admob is never shown

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to display an Admob ad but it's never shown. This is so weird.

This is my implementation:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/containerGlobal"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#C7CFD9"/>
```

And the code:

```
ViewGroup holder = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.containerGlobal);

        AdView adView = new AdView( this, AdSize.BANNER, "adunit..." );
        holder.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

        adRequest.addTestDevice("5A33BC58556417FFF74F329CDFA95B7E");
        adRequest.addTestDevice("8DAC38F2726F4802D60BF7EBA8A5FC39");

        adView.loadAd( adRequest );
```

Logcat:
[image]

Any tips?

**Edit**

This is my code now:

[image: enter code here]

And logcat output... Looks like everything is working, but nothing is shown...

[image]

**Edit 2 **
Several hours later, still have the issue.

Comment: When you say nothing is shown, what exactly happens? Do you see the test ad?

Comment: nothing means nothing is shown in view. Even if I use archierarchy view, I see nothing related to ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Finally solved. it was all related with my layouts. I don't really know what was the issue, just removed some of them, changed params of them, and it's being shown now.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise your AdView, try doing the following after it:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "adUnitId");

adView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)adView .getLayoutParams(); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); 
adView.setLayoutParams(params);

holder.addView(adView);
```

To set the height/width of the add, and then it's position at the bottom-centre of the screen.

Comment: What happens if you set your 'holder' variable be of type RelativeLayout instead of ViewGroup? Also, which device is this on? I've had issues with some, especially Nexus', where the Ad just takes forever to actually appear.

Comment: Changed Holder to LinearLayout and still happening. I'm using GenyMotion emulating a Nexus, and on my real Nexus 5. Going to try an old 2.3 emulator.

Answer (score -1):

instead of "adunit..." place there your real publisher ID that can be found on admob page

Comment: Obv i'm placing my real one, I just removed it so it's not public, lol.